# DirectX 10 apps run with integrated GPU, but not with Nvidia GPU

Tags: windows-7, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, directx, directx-11

I've just performed a fresh install of Windows 7 x64 on my Toshiba Satellite Laptop but it seems that I'm unable to run some DX10 apps using the Nvidia 740M GPU, but they run with the integrated Intel GPU.

I've tried both with Passmarks's PerformanceTest (run a DX10 benchmark) and with Civilization 5 (DX10 game that once ran fine on this laptop), and both hang with the Nvidia GPU, but they run with the Intel GPU.

This was with all latest drivers and OS updates. I've reinstalled two different older Nvidia drivers (353.30 and 359.06) and also reinstalled DirectX (KB2670838), the apps will still hang if ran using the Nvidia GPU.

Not sure if it's helpful but I had to install the [DirectX End-User Runtimes (June 2010)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109) because of Civ5.

Comment: Windows 7 fully supports DX10, your inability to run DX10 applications, has to do missing drivers.  The linked executable is for DX9 and has nothing to do with DX10.

Comment: I've tried 3 versions of the Nvidia drivers, none of them worked, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: The question wasn't whether DX10 is installed but rather why do DX10 apps hang when using the Nvidia GPU. Is something unclear in the information provided?

Comment: google 341.44 notebook drivers and install this specific version and report please